# Salvar XML sem formatação

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Eu preciso gerar o `xml`, porém sem pular linha, da forma que eu gero ele está todo identado, como eu faço para salvar sem pular a linha?

```
document.LoadXml(soapEnvelope);
document.Save(@"E:\nota.xml");
```

Eu tentei este código abaixo:

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Load("arquivo.xml");
document.Save("arquivo2.xml", SaveOptions.DisableFormatting);
```

Porém não aparece a opção `SaveOptions`, utilizo `ASP.NET CORE`.
Este é o método inteiro:

```
private void montaEnvelope(HttpWebRequest webRequest, XmlDocument document)
{
     string soapEnvelope = string.Empty;
     soapEnvelope += "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:ws=\"http://ws.issweb.fiorilli.com.br/\" xmlns:xd=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#\">";
     soapEnvelope += "<soapenv:Header/><soapenv:Body><ws:gerarNfse>";
     soapEnvelope += document.LastChild.OuterXml.Replace("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>", string.Empty);
     soapEnvelope += "<username>01001001000113</username><password>123456</password></ws:gerarNfse></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>";

     MemoryStream stream = stringToStream(soapEnvelope);
     webRequest.ContentLength = stream.Length;
     Stream requestStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream();
     stream.WriteTo(requestStream);

     document.LoadXml(soapEnvelope);
     document.Save(@"E:\nota.xml");
     XDocument document1 = XDocument.Load(@"E:\nota.xml");
     this.XmlDocNFSe = document;
}
```

Comment: Tem certeza? porque está dentro do `namespace` `System.Xml.Linq`, você adicionou?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic quando eu coloco `System.Xml.Linq` ele deixa eu colocar o `SaveOptions.DisableFormatting`, porém ele retorna este Erro Nenhuma sobrecarga para o método "Save" leva 2 argumentos

Comment: Estranho de mais ... !

Comment: @VirgilioNovic acabei de editar com a função inteira, assim você pode ver como está sendo declarado o `document`. Obrigado.

Comment: Qual versão do netframework?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic utilizo 4.7.2 e do core é 2.1

Comment: XmlDocument não tem mesmo vc já direitinho o nome das classes

Comment: Não entendi o que você quis dizer.

Comment: No seu parametro está XmlDocument que é diferente de XDocument você está errando nas classes onde XDocument realmente tem a sobrecarga com SaveOptions já XmlDocument não tem essa sobrecarga !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Veja você está confundido as classes, a que você está utilizando pelo parâmetro do método é `XmlDocument` que não tem a sobrecarga com o parâmetro `SaveOptions`, mas, existe um caminho para salvar o `XmlDocument` ***sem formatação***:

***Exemplo:***

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

using(XmlTextWriter wr = new XmlTextWriter(fileName, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    wr.Formatting = Formatting.None;
    doc.Save(wr);
}
```

<sub>Código referencia: [Is there any way to save an XmlDocument *without* indentation and line returns?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4725021/6797930)</sub>

Ou seja, `XDocument` é a classe que tem uma sobrecarga com `SaveOptions`, diferente no que está no seu código.

<sub>***Referencia:*** [Is there any way to save an XmlDocument *without* indentation and line returns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724940/is-there-any-way-to-save-an-xmldocument-without-indentation-and-line-returns)</sub>